# Função simulando if no php

Tags: php

Seria possível minimizar ou fazer uma função que tenha o mesmo funcionamento desse código abaixo?

```
                        if($rank <= 50){ 
                            echo 'Descolorido';
                        }
                        else if($rank <= 100){ 
                            echo 'Azul Bebê';
                        }
                        else if($rank <= 200){ 
                            echo 'Roxo Bacon';
                        } 
                        else if($rank <= 300){ 
                            echo 'Verde ET';
                        } 
                        else if($rank <= 500){ 
                            echo 'Marrom Madeira';
                        } 
                        else if($rank <= 700){ 
                            echo 'Laranja Power';
                        } 
                        else if($rank <= 900){ 
                            echo 'Vermelho Killer';
                        } 
                        else if($rank <= 1500){ 
                            echo 'Rosa Piriguete';
                        } 
                        else if($rank <= 1700){ 
                            echo 'Amarelo Bobba';
                        } 
                        else if($rank <= 2000){ 
                            echo 'Turquesa Maravilha';
                        } 
                        else if($rank <= 2300){ 
                            echo 'Gótica Má';
                        } 
                        else if($rank <= 2500){ 
                            echo 'Ametista Destruidor';
                        } 
                        else if($rank <= 2700){ 
                            echo 'Esmeralda Divindade';
                        } 
                        else if($rank <= 3000){ 
                            echo 'Púrpura Star';
                        } 
                        else if($rank <= 3500){ 
                            echo 'Dourado Rei';
                        } 
                        else if($rank >= 3500){ 
                            echo 'Rainbow';
                        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mover as comparações para um *loop* e mapear com um *array* de regras pode ficar mais legível:

```
function determineRank($input) {
    // valor retornado caso $input seja maior que todos os $ranks
    $default = 'Rainbow';
    $ranks = [
        50 => 'Descolorido',
        100 => 'Azul Bebê',
        200 => 'Roxo Bacon',
        300 => 'Verde ET',
        500 => 'Marrom Madeira',
        700 => 'Laranja Power',
        900 => 'Vermelho Killer',
        1500 => 'Rosa Piriguete',
        1700 => 'Amarelo Bobba',
        2000 => 'Turquesa Maravilha',
        2300 => 'Gótica Má',
        2500 => 'Ametista Destruidor',
        2700 => 'Esmeralda Divindade',
        3000 => 'Púrpura Star',
        3500 => 'Dourado Rei',
    ];

    foreach ($ranks as $rank => $value) {
        if ($input <= $rank) {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    return $default;
}

// Exemplo
$input = rand(45, 3600);
echo $input . ' - ' . determineRank($input) . PHP_EOL;
```

Por casa da função `rand()` toda fez que executar o script ele irá gerar um número aleatório de 45 até 3600 (um intervalo que engloba todas os possível valores) e escreve qual o valor e seu retorno

Veja em [execução](https://3v4l.org/0D3Vs) no 3v4l.org. No final fiz um loop para chamar a função 20 vezes com valores diferentes:

```
1873 - Turquesa Maravilha 
2440 - Ametista Destruidor 
1947 - Turquesa Maravilha 
1263 - Rosa Piriguete 
3344 - Dourado Rei 
2266 - Gótica Má 
516 - Laranja Power 
188 - Roxo Bacon 
2865 - Púrpura Star 
1052 - Rosa Piriguete 
2403 - Ametista Destruidor 
3118 - Dourado Rei 
2248 - Gótica Má 
2335 - Ametista Destruidor 
738 - Vermelho Killer 
1021 - Rosa Piriguete 
2026 - Gótica Má 
1733 - Turquesa Maravilha 
289 - Verde ET 
2094 - Gótica Má
```

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem como exibir o rank com determinada quantidade de mensagens.

Comment: Acho que você entendeu um pouco errado. A função se baseia em por ex: determineRank($quantidadedemensagens) e vai exibir a tarja equivalente a essa quantidade. Por exemplo: <= 50 é Descolorido ficaria assim na teoria (suponto que tenho 45 mensagens): determineRank(45) e exibiria Descolorido, porquê 45 é menor que 50 (<=)

Comment: Acredito que o código dele deveria ser `determineRank($input)` e assim faz exatamente o que você precisa.

Comment: Valeu @AndersonCarlosWoss. O rand() ia gerar um valor aleatório todo momento, por isso não estava batendo :)

Comment: @PauloSérgioFilho corrigi o exemplo. A lógica está correta, só o exemplo que estava errado

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado!

Comment: Eu tinha tentado antes usar a função diretamente assim como o @AndersonCarlosWoss falou, mas não tinha dado certo. Provavelmente tinha feito algo errado! :)